# insert excel file into oracle 11g blob field with sqlj

Tags: java, oracle, blob, sqlj

I have the following problem. In oracle java I create an excel file, then i want to store it in a blob field. When I try to insert into the table i get a java.lang.ClassCastException:

```
Error SQL: ORA-29532: llamada Java terminada por una excepción Java no resuelta: java.lang.ClassCastException
    29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
    *Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
               resolved by the Java code.
    *Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

The code that intended to insert the excel into the database:

```
Workbook wb=null;
byte[] xlsInBytes=null;
ByteArrayOutputStream excelOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wb=new HSSFWorkbook();  
wb.write(excelOutputStream);
xlsInBytes=excelOutputStream.toByteArray();
Blob blobExcel=new  javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(xlsInBytes); 
#sql {insert into MYTABLE(file_id,excelfile) 
    values(1,:blobExcel)};
```

At the #sql line i get the above error.

If I replace the :blobExcel with empty_blob() then it runs without problem.
It also runs when I replace the

```
Blob blobExcel=new  javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(xlsInBytes);
```

with

```
Blob blobExcel=null;
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Sz.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: After posting my question I realized that not everything is okay with it, but I can't find a way to modify it...

Comment: There should be an "edit" button right underneath the tags.

Comment: Thanks, I was focusing on the highlighted tags and not the gray links below them. :) Hope now my question fits better to your rules.